# How to show product object?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

In Shopify if we print title of product then we can use like :

```
{{ product.title }}
```

If we want to show whole object that includes whole data of product how we can do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [JSON filter](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/additional-filters#json) .

If you like to output it directly on the frontend you use it like so: `{{ product | json }}`

But its much better to log it as a javascript object like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log({{ product | json }});
</script>
```

Comment: Great answer, this worked for me and should be accepted.